# Reshaping Dataframe: Pivot, Stack or Groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
Playlist    Track Name    Spotify Uri               Playlist Uri
microhouse  make a move   5nUS4bSN0cFZB0knxyM4LZ    1d4gyZxan7lK9KqYU2EJ    
microhouse  mango         2f8eSlsreAHHzJ5SPkpYLf    1d4gyZxan7lK9KqYU2EJ    
attlas      ryat          3McvalY1RDYczyDmixyAwQ    2CInjKguWauO29QB21Co
attlas      further       4qEUN1lON8UjnUiOZc39ID    2CInjKguWauO29QB21Co
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Playlist         microhouse                         attlas      
Playlist Uri     1d4gyZxan7lK9KqY                   2CInjKguWauO29Q                      
                 Track Name      Spotify Uri        Track Name   Spotify Uri  
                 make a move     5nUS4bSN0cFZB0kn   ryat         3valY1RDYc
                 mango           2f8eSlsreAHHzJ5S   further      4qEUN1lON
```

I have used pivot which produces a column for each Playlist and all the Track Names in that playlist, but I don't know how to do it with a Multi index(Playlist and Playlist URI), no aggregation and for two value columns (Track Name and Spotify URI). Stack doesn't really do what I want either. Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 3 level MultiIndex in columns with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new `index` and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), last if necessary sort second level by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), change level ordering by [`reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) and also [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for change ordering:

```
g = df.groupby(['Playlist','Playlist Uri']).cumcount()
df = (df.set_index([g, 'Playlist','Playlist Uri'])
        .unstack([1,2])
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
        .reorder_levels([1,2,0], axis=1)
        .reindex(['Track Name','Spotify Uri'], axis=1, level=2))
print (df)
Playlist                   attlas                          \
Playlist Uri 2CInjKguWauO29QB21Co                           
                       Track Name             Spotify Uri   
0                            ryat  3McvalY1RDYczyDmixyAwQ   
1                         further  4qEUN1lON8UjnUiOZc39ID   

Playlist               microhouse                          
Playlist Uri 1d4gyZxan7lK9KqYU2EJ                          
                       Track Name             Spotify Uri  
0                     make a move  5nUS4bSN0cFZB0knxyM4LZ  
1                           mango  2f8eSlsreAHHzJ5SPkpYLf
```

---

```
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['attlas', 'microhouse'], 
                   ['1d4gyZxan7lK9KqYU2EJ', '2CInjKguWauO29QB21Co'], 
                   ['Track Name', 'Spotify Uri']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['Playlist', 'Playlist Uri', None])
```

Comment: This worked great. Thank you very much. I was just wondering why you reindex at the end?